# Apache graphs and data not updating in Munin on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, munin

So I am rebuilding a server from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04; not doing the upgrade path because I would rather build from scratch in this case. I have installed Munin as I have done before in Ubuntu 12.04 like this:

```
sudo aptitude install munin munin-node
```

Then I enabled the Apache modules for Munin like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache_accesses /etc/munin/plugins/apache_accesses
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache_processes /etc/munin/plugins/apache_processes
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache_volume /etc/munin/plugins/apache_volume
```

Then I restarted the Munin node like this:

```
sudo service munin-node restart
```

And waited the requisite 5-10 minutes to get data and related graphs generated. And happily the graphs showed up! But unhappily, all the values were `-nan`, meaning somehow the data was not being processed by Munin; see screenshot below:

[image: Munin Apache graphs without data.]

Usually this means Munin is having problems reaching the localhost’s Apache `service-status` page, but checking that URL on the system with Lynx shows everything works fine:

```
lynx http://localhost/server-status
```

So I am stumped as to what might have happened. Did a full system restart and 100% no improvement. What could be happening?

[image: Apache service status page viewable via Lynx.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this! Getting frustrated as heck about this issue, I ran a Munin module suggest command like this:

```
sudo munin-node-configure --suggest
```

In the piles of output here are the relevant Apache related lines:

```
apache_accesses            | yes  | no [LWP::UserAgent not found]          
apache_processes           | yes  | no [LWP::UserAgent not found]          
apache_volume              | yes  | no [LWP::UserAgent not found]
```

So the modules are active, but that `[LWP::UserAgent not found]`? What’s up with that? Did some Googling [and found this article that explains it](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/4/9/enabling-munin-node-plug-ins-on-ubuntu):

> It's not the most helpful suggestion you're likely to come across,
>   granted, but with a little research it might make more sense.
>   Fortunately we can skip the research in this case and get right down
>   to what it means: Munin is actually a collection of scripts written in
>   a language called Perl, and "LWP::UserAgent" is a Perl library. So the
>   fact that LWP::UserAgent wasn't found means that particular Perl
>   library isn't installed on our example slice.

Since Munin is a bunch of Perl scripts, that `LWP` error was connected to [`libwww-perl`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/) which is basically the “The World-Wide Web library for Perl.” So Munin was failing because it had no client library installed to connect to the Apache server status page. I was able to solve that issue by just installing `libwww-perl` like this:

```
sudo aptitude install libwww-perl
```

With that done, I ran that Munin module suggest command again and all looks good with no `LWP` related errors:

```
apache_accesses            | yes  | yes                                    
apache_processes           | yes  | yes                                    
apache_volume              | yes  | yes
```

So I just waited another 5-10 minutes and et voilà! Munin can now read the Apache server status data and the graphs are now properly updated and working as expected:

[image: Munin Apache graphs without data.]